# the search function does not work using angular

Tags: angular

I want to search by slug, I have my slug successfully, and when I want to show my table it gives me undefined.

```
slug:string ='';
   categoriesS!:any[];

   categories:any[]=[
    {id:1,  name:"emploi",                      slug:"emploi"                },
    {id:2,  name:"vehicule",                    slug:"auto-moto"             },
      ];

filterAnnonces(slug:string){ 
    this.categoriesS = this.categories.filter( item => 
        {
          item.slug == slug,
          console.log( this.categoriesS)
         }
    );
}
```

Comment: filter expected a comparison. try removing console log line, and add a return in front of the item.slug==slug line

Comment: @smcrowley: return is not needed before the comparison. Also if the slug parameter does not match any of the slugs in the category array, the categoriesS array will be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
filterAnnonces(slug:string){ 
    return this.categories.filter( item => 
        {
          return item.slug == slug
         }
    );
}
```